# Different shading for multi-parted tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, shading

Please consider MWE below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{abstract} =  [draw=gray, 
                        inner sep = 0.2cm,
                        rounded corners, 
                        rectangle split, 
                        rectangle split parts=3, 
                        % shade=rectangle, 
                        % left color=blue!10!white,
                        % rectangle split part fill={blue!30!white,blue!20!white,blue!10!white}, %This will fill them, but not shade! Moreover, I prefer not to do it this way
                        every text node part/.style={fill=blue!20!white}, %This is not working
                        every two node part/.style={text width=6cm},
                        every three node part/.style={text=blue}]
\tikz
        \node (Item)[abstract]  
        {
            \textbf{Foo}
            \nodepart{two}\lipsum[1]
            \nodepart{three}\textsl{Bar}
        };
\end{document}
```

This creates tikz node with three parts but no filling (Fig. Left). Somehow the line below is doing nothing:

```
every text node part/.style={fill=blue!20!white}
```

Next line fills the rectangles (Fig. Center) but I prefer to do it with `every` command:

```
rectangle split part fill={blue!30!white,blue!20!white,blue!10!white}
```

What I eventually want, is to have different gradient shadings for each part, preferably using `every XXX node part/.style` (e.g. Fig. Right).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package? It looks it is designed very well for this sort of shading tasks.

Comment: @Malipivo, I know about that package. What I want to do however, is out of the boundaries of tcolorbox. What you see above is just the tip of the iceberg `;)`

Comment: I see, I would start putting individual nodes on each other if your requirements are this high.

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge TikZ is not offering such feature, yet. This is an example where I used several independent nodes to get that effect.

```
%! *latex mal-nodepart.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[m/.style={text width=5cm, anchor=north, draw},
  every node/.style={m},
  first/.style={shade, left color=white, right color=blue, align=center, font=\bfseries},
  second/.style={shade, right color=green, font=\small, text=yellow},
  third/.style={shade, left color=red, align=center, font=\bfseries},
  ]
\node[first] (first) {My heading};
\node[second] (second) at (first.south) {\kant[1]};
\node[third] (third) at (second.south) {My footing};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thank you. But I'm afraid using multiple stacked nodes is my failsafe. This is what I'm doing right now but I need to do it more systematically. I will wait for some other answers if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course, please have no worries!